# Obfuscating a client - server with serialization and objects sent through sockets

Tags: serialization, proguard

Yeah - so I can't figure out how to make it work.

Basically as soon as the client is obfuscated, it doesn't recognise the classes being sent by the server - which breaks the software.

Any ideas?

Comment: Err, obfuscate the classes being sent by the server?

Comment: @EJP I'll give it a go